# ImportError: No module named 'util'

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, python-import

When I try to import the module `illustris_python` I get the error

> ImportError: No module named 'util'

The module `util` is in the directory below the module `snapshot.py` that needs it, so I am confused as to why Python sees one module, but not the other.

I have included the import call as well as traceback below.

```
Python 3.4.3 (v3.4.3:9b73f1c3e601, Feb 24 2015, 22:44:40) [MSC v.1600 64 bit (AMD64)]
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 3.0.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.
%guiref   -> A brief reference about the graphical user interface.

In [1]: import illustris_python as il
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-1-ff06d24b4811>", line 1, in <module>
    import illustris_python as il

  File "C:\WinPython-64bit-3.4.3.2\python-3.4.3.amd64\lib\site-packages\illustris_python\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from . import *

  File "C:\WinPython-64bit-3.4.3.2\python-3.4.3.amd64\lib\site-packages\illustris_python\snapshot.py", line 6, in <module>
    from util import partTypeNum

ImportError: No module named 'util'


In [2]:
```

Screenshot showing location of `util`:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: is that directory on your PYTHONPATH?

Comment: @dbliss: His `site-packages` really shouldn't be on his `PYTHONPATH`. It'll end up on `sys.path` anyway.

Comment: Possibility 1: Are you running from inside the directory you cloned/unzipped/whatever `illustris_python` into? If so, it can easily get confused about the local copies vs. the installed copies.

Comment: @dbliss it is not in the PYTHONPATH.

Comment: Possibility 2: Does `illustris_python` support Python 3?

Comment: Meanwhile… how did you install this? The only thing I can find named `illustris_python` is a [repo of sample files on BitBucket](https://bitbucket.org/illustris/illustris_python/) that doesn't include a `setup.py` or any manual installation instructions. If you had to guess how to install it because they didn't tell you, I'd be surprising if you guessed everything 100% right; I'm sure I wouldn't get it right without some debugging. :)

Comment: @abarnert I am pretty sure that it is not being ran from inside the directory. I am using the Winpythin version of IPython which I open through the start menu.

Comment: @abarnert hmm, that might be it. I had to rewrite a few lines that were written in 2.x

Comment: OK, that's exactly the problem; it's a Python 2-vs.-3 bug. Let me write an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at [the BitBucket repo](https://bitbucket.org/illustris/illustris_python/), I'm pretty sure the problem is that this code is Python 2.x-only. Someone's done some work to clean it up for an eventual port, but there's still more to be done.

This particular error is [near the top of `snapshot.py`](https://bitbucket.org/illustris/illustris_python/src/default/snapshot.py?at=default#cl-6):

```
from util import partTypeNum
```

In Python 2.6, this is a *relative* import (it's "deprecated" by [PEP 328](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/#timeline), but I'm pretty sure you don't actually get the warning by default…), so it first looks in the same package as `snapshot.py`, where it finds a `util.py`, before looking through your `sys.path`.

In Python 3.4, it's an *absolute* import, so it just looks in your `sys.path` (well, it calls your top-level module finders, but usually that means looking in your `sys.path`), and there is no `util.py` there.

If you're trying to finish porting this sample code to 3.x yourself, just change it to an explicit relative import:

```
from .util import partTypeNum
```

Comment: @abarnet changed all of the modules to an explicit relative import, but now I get the error in the `__intit__` module

Comment: @Surfcast23: You mean `__init__`, not `_int_`, right? I wouldn't be surprised if this isn't the only Python 2-vs.-3 bug in the whole project. If you want to port it yourself, you're going to have to try to debug all the problems you can, and open new questions for each one where you get stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Right now I have solve the problem you have. What I have done is open the terminal in the direction of "illustris_python". Hope it could be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue. I noticed the library need to have access to a file titled.util.py. I just copied the file from the related github, and pasted in the folder where the library was installed.