# python : ImportError: No module named utils with clean_string

Tags: python

Note: I have already check question with same error as mine but mine is different i want to ask if "clean_string, clean_number, clean_text, clean_float, clean_int"

**`agency_id = scrapy.Field(serializer=clean_string)`**

are some in built function in python or i have to import to make it work

I am new in python just doing some programming stuffs.

Below i my code snippet

```
from .utils import clean_string, clean_number, clean_text, clean_float, clean_int
from six.moves.urllib.parse import urljoin

class MyItem(scrapy.Item):
    # define the fields for your item here like:
    # name = scrapy.Field()
    agency_id = scrapy.Field(serializer=clean_string)
```

when i run above code it give me error

```
**ImportError: No module named utils**
```

can you help with it have i to install **clean_string** or something

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ImportError: No module named 'util'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29957477/importerror-no-module-named-util)

Comment: hey my issue is different please  check : clean_string

Comment: Check this out http://nullege.com/codes/show/src@a@r@archivematica-HEAD@src@archivematicaCommon@lib@externals@pyes@query.py/11/utils.clean_string

Comment: is it Django utils?

Comment: hey but have i to install clean_string ? as when i write below code it give utils error

Answer (score 0):

As per our discussion, please install `python -m pip install pyes`

do it as below:

```
from pyes import utils

# use it like below
class MyItem(scrapy.Item):
    # define the fields for your item here like:
    # name = scrapy.Field()
    agency_id = scrapy.Field(serializer=utils.clean_string)
```

(or)

```
from pyes.utils import clean_string

# use it like below
class MyItem(scrapy.Item):
    # define the fields for your item here like:
    # name = scrapy.Field()
    agency_id = scrapy.Field(serializer=clean_string)
```

you cannot use `from .utils import clean_string` because it looks for `utils` in current working directory. Instead either use `from django import utils` (or) use `from pyes.utils import clean_string`

Comment: have i to install django

Comment: if you are developing or writing this code as part of django web application. Yes, you have to install django by `python -m pip install django`.

Comment: i did install with ur command and ran code now it gave error : from django.utils import clean_string, clean_number, clean_text, clean_float, clean_int
ImportError: cannot import name clean_string

Comment: are you developing this to extract data from web pages using scrapy? Because I see that it is scrapy.Item? Please confirm

Comment: yeah i am using scrapy.org

Comment: can you tell what i am mising

Comment: @pcoder, is there utils folder in the same directory of this file?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122603/discussion-between-be-good-do-good-and-pcoder).